# Subtracting Days From Current Date

Tags: sql-server-2012, datetime, date

I know this is probably very basic, but I'm trying to create a calculated field that subtracts X number of  from Current Date, based off of the value of another field:

```
CASE WHEN DaysPD = 30 THEN 1
     WHEN DaysPD = 180 THEN 6
     WHEN DaysPD = 360 THEN 12
 END AS MonthsPD

CASE WHEN RateCode = 'AC' THEN RateResetDate - MonthsPD
```

In this example, if the `RateResetDate = '03/08/2019'` and `MonthsPD = 6`, then I would want the calculation to be `'03/08/2019' - 6 Months = '10/8/2018'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to do that:

```
CASE WHEN [RateCode] = 'AC'
      THEN DATEADD(MONTH, 
            CASE WHEN DaysPD = 30 THEN -1 
                 WHEN DaysPD = 180 THEN -6 
                 WHEN DaysPD = 360 THEN -12 
             END,
           [RateResetDate]) 
    END AS [AdjustedDate]
```

Alternatively, you can just pass in the days if you want:

```
CASE WHEN [RateCode] = 'AC'
      THEN DATEADD(DAY, -DaysPD, [RateResetDate]) 
    END AS [AdjustedDate]
```

Comment: Wow, I was really overthinking that one.  That works perfect, Thank you!!

Comment: @MikeJones no problem!

Comment: Mind that if `DaysPD` value is neither 30, 180 or 360, you'll get an implicit `ELSE NULL` in the CASE expression and NULL as a result for `AdjustedDate`. You may prefer to add an `ELSE 0` for example, to cover those cases.